# Supported cordova version for xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using XCode 7.2.1 to compile my ionic app. The problem is, if I'm using the latest cordova, it will display this error

`GCDWebServerDataRequest.m - No visible @interface for 'NSDATA' declares the selector 'appendData:'`

I googled and found the error is because I'm not using the latest XCode. However, I can't install the latest XCode because of insufficient storage space in my MacBook (can't upgrade my OSX). Furthermore, I believe I don't need to have the latest XCode, since I won't be distributing the compiled app in App Store later; I will only distribute it in my company's internal App Store.

So where can I get the info on which cordova is supported for XCode 7.2.1? Later I believe I can just install the supported cordova version by running `sudo npm install -g cordova@[version]` right?

Thanks

Comment: May I know the reason why you are still using pretty old Xcode, when you can't even submit the apps to App Store using it?

Comment: @Satyam I've mentioned the reason in my question above